# Set up listeners only after permission is verified

Tags: react-native

I am using **react-native-notifications** - Version 2.1.7 library to receive notifications in a **react-native** mobile app. I don't want to set up the notification-related listeners **until the user has provided permission** to receive notifications.

Q1. The documentation says that it is highly recommended to keep listeners registration at global scope rather than at screen scope. **What problems should I expect if I set up listeners at a screen,** at which the user is asked to provide permission?

Q2. The device token listener `NotificationsAndroid.setRegistrationTokenUpdateListener()` does NOT seem to work if it is inside a promise. **What am I missing here?** Please, see my code below.

```js
// This function is called when the user clicks on the button "Provide permission to receive notifications."
const _requestPermissionNotification = async () => {
    let hasPermission = false; 
    try {
        hasPermission = await NotificationsAndroid.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications();
    }
    catch (error) {
        Alert.alert(
            "Notification", 
            "To utilise the full functionality of this app, Permission to receive notifications is required.", 
            [{ text: "Ok." }] 
        );
    } // end of: try/catch 

    if (hasPermission) {
        // A. Register Token 
        // THIS LISTENER DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK UNLESS IT IS SET UP OUTSIDE THE COMPONENT! 
        NotificationsAndroid.setRegistrationTokenUpdateListener((deviceToken) => {
            console.log("PermissionsScreen - setRegistrationTokenUpdateListener - deviceToken:", deviceToken);
        });
        // B. Pending Notifications
        PendingNotifications.getInitialNotification()
            .then((notification) => {
                console.log("PermissionsScreen - getInitialNotification - notification:", notification);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error("getInitialNotifiation failed", err));
        // C. Notification Opened
        NotificationsAndroid.setNotificationOpenedListener((notification) => {
            console.log("PermissionsScreen - setNotificationOpenedListener - :data", notification.getData());
        });
        // D.a Notification Received 
        NotificationsAndroid.setNotificationReceivedListener((notification) => {
            console.log("PermissionsScreen - setNotificationReceivedListener - data:", notification.getData());
        });
        // D.b Notification Received "IN FOREGROUND"
        NotificationsAndroid.setNotificationReceivedInForegroundListener((notification) => {
            console.log("PermissionsScreen - setNotificationReceivedInForegroundListener (foreground)", notification.getData());
        });
    } // end of: if()
}; // end of: _requestPermissionNotification()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that version 3.1.1 of React-Native-Notifications does not have these limitations anymore.

The following code, which uses the new commands, can be used inside a promise and inside a component.

```js
// Step A.1: Register this app to receive notifications.
Notifications.registerRemoteNotifications(); 

// Step A.2: Get the device token 
Notifications.events().registerRemoteNotificationsRegistered( (event) => { 
    console.log("deviceToken:", event.deviceToken);
});
```